# Keep the same accept ratio when device orientation was changed

Tags: reactjs, video-streaming, opentok

Is it possible to keep the same accept ratio when device orientation was changed?
Maybe, is there some way to have the equals screen sizes(resolutions) that would not depend on device rotation.

**EDIT:**
So, basically, my question is:

1. Is it possible to make a square video resolution?
2. Is it possible to lock changing of resolution during the changing device orientation?

Please check the screen that I wanted to improve.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adam here from the OpenTok team. I'm presuming that you are using the JS sdk because you tagged reactjs. If you size the Subscriber to be a square and you set the fitMode to be 'cover' (which it is by default) then it will crop out the video to be square.

Comment: Hi Adam! Thank you for your help. However, the thing that I need the square streaming size. So, it would be streamed equally everywhere e.g.: Youtube channel.

Comment: By default OpenTok will just take your Camera stream and stream it. The supported default resolutions in OpenTok are the ones supported by most cameras, 640x480 (default), 320x240 and 1280x720. If you want to stream a resolution other than this you will need to create a custom stream using a Canvas. Have a look at this sample app to get an idea how to create a custom stream based on a camera stream.
https://github.com/opentok/opentok-web-samples/tree/master/Stream-Filter